# Copying/yanking to the system clipboard in spacemacs (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, spacemacs

I cannot seem to figure out how to copy text from an open emacs file in the terminal to my system clipboard (e.g., to copy into an email).

I've read a number of other questions and have the following in my `dotspacemacs/user-config()` function:

```
(setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)
(setq interprogram-paste-function 'x-cut-buffer-or-selection-value)
```

but it still isn't working.

This is using evil-mode and spacemacs.

Comment: so, to clarify, you're running emacs in terminal mode, eg. `emacs -nw`?  If so, I would guess those `x-` variables/functions aren't in effect

Comment: [This answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/22272/11) suggests two solutions: set `allowWindowOps` in xterm settings, or use [the xclip package](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/xclip.html).